# How should I prove $\Box (\Box p \rightarrow q) \vee \Box (\Box q \rightarrow \Box p)$ using KT45.

Tags: logic, modal-logic

How am I supposed to prove the same using natural deduction? I started my proof with a LEM 
$$\Box (\Box p \rightarrow \Box q) \vee \neg \Box (\Box p \rightarrow \Box q)$$
I split the LEM via $\vee$ elimination, take the part before the $\vee$, and then add $\Box (\Box q \rightarrow p)$ by $\vee$ introduction.

Now for the part after the $\vee$ in the LEM. How am I supposed to use it to reach my conclusion?  I tried by assuming $\neg \Box \Box (q \rightarrow p)$, my intention being that I would able to prove it wrong and thereby proving $\Box \Box (q \rightarrow p)$ being true, and thereafter is trivial.

Any help on this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Amzoti: Could you please elaborate

Comment: I was looking at the pre-edited version - so ignore.

Comment: @user1791452 What sort of natural deduction proof system are you using?  Something like Konyndyk's systems that have modal subproofs?